# Correct way to give path to lookup table in rasa

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa, rasa-core

I want to add a look up table for rasa nlu training. I have created a cities.txt file in my data folder and added it in my nlu.md file as

```
## lookup:location
   data/cities.txt
```

when I try to train the model using `rasa train nlu` I get an error

```
ValueError: Could not load lookup table data/cities.txt. Please make sure you've provided the correct path.
```

What is the correct way for giving the path?

### Edit

I am using a Windows system:

```
cmd prompt => C:\Users\1000277196\Desktop\ChatBot> rasa train nlu
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the path is correct relative to where you are running the `rasa train` command? If you are in the directory `my-project`, the file should be at `my-project/data/cities.txt`

Comment: yes, I am doing the same way. Do you think its something related to rasa on windows?